# How do I specify the size of the domain of action in the function CycleIndexPolynomial?

Tags: permutation, group-theory

If I input

```
CycleIndexPolynomial[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, 5}]]
```

Mathematica returns 1; I was hoping for $x_1^5$.

If I input

```
CycleIndexPolynomial[{1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6}, Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, 6}]]
```

Mathematica returns $x_1 x_2^2$; I need $x_1^2 x_2^2$.

Comment: Please take the time to [format your question properly](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: `CycleIndexPolynomial[Cycles[{}], {Subscript[x, i]}, 5]` gives $x_1^5$

Comment: @ paw  Yes thank you. I was a little aggravated at Mathematica when I posted this question.  I have now restated the question.

Comment: @ m_goldberg  Yes thank you.  I see now that I should have read the "help" section for this function more carefully as this issue is addressed there.